# Find Voltage between two terminals

Tags: voltage, resistance, terminal

I have the circuit below and I need to find the voltage between the terminals A and B, which steps do I need to follow? And if there are several methods to do so, what are they?

[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts about solving this?

Comment: @O.: (1) What is the voltage at 'a'? (2) What is the voltage at 'b'? (3) What is the difference between them?

Comment: This is a homework problem, I found that the voltage in the 24 ohms resistor is 8 V while for the 12 ohms resistor it is 4V, the difference between the 24 and the 12 ohms resistors is 4V, it's not the solution. I was hoping for tips and tricks, not a solution to the problem.

Comment: Guys, even this is homework question. I think it's effort to find solution in here. @O. Sinno you need to find current with Ohm's law and then calculate voltage on point A and on point B. Then just do A - B. Answer is going to be negative

Comment: @jalaffo then I had the answer all along, but why is it negative?

Comment: @O.Sinno 1) A point of nomenclature: the potential difference is *across* a component, not through it. 2) The voltage \$\textrm V_x\$ is 8 V, as you determined, so the voltage at b is 8 V *with respect to the negative lead of the voltage source*. The voltage at a is 4 V. You want the potential difference between a and b, which is (a-b), or -4 V.

Comment: You can just look at it and say -4V. There's 1/3 of 12V across the left 12 ohms and 2/3 of 12V across the right 24 ohms so the difference is -1/3 of 12V.  But I would suggest calling the lower nodes ground and applying the voltage divider formula on each side.

Answer (score 1):

Not many "tricks" for this one. Best to choose a reference point from where you measure all the voltages. By habit, most of us would choose the bottom-most node (I suspect that @Transistor has chosen this point when he asks *"What the voltage at 'a'?*).

One trick *for this particular circuit* is to recognize the symmetry. One branch is the inverse of the other branch. So you need only solve either 'Va' or solve 'Vb' voltage. Then compare with half the supply voltage. Double the difference to get the solution of 'V(ab)'. This 'trick' may seem a bit round-about.

A different way of viewing the symmetry trick takes the voltage 'Va', and applies Kirchhoff's voltage law: 'Va' + V(ba) + 'Va' = 12V. Be wary of the signs of these voltages...is the required solution "voltage on A with-respect-to-B", or is it "voltage on B with-respect-to-A" ?. It may be best to state your solution: *voltage on B is more positive than voltage on A by X volts*...this is unambiguous. As a sanity-check, if the magnitude of your solution of V(ab) is larger than 12V, you've made a sign-error.

Are tricks worth the trouble? A non-symmetrical choice of resistors forces the long solution: solve voltage 'a' & 'b' in each branch separately, then subtract to find the difference. This smells somewhat like superposition, where signs of voltages or currents can drive you crazy.

Answer (score 1):

My simple "no calculation" (well, hardly any) trick is to see that you have two voltage dividers.

The voltage at point A will be 12/(12 + 24) * 12 = 4 volts.

The voltages at B and between A and B are left as exercises for the student. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer the question just as you asked it.

You need to solve for the element voltages in the circuit, then use those to determine the voltage difference in question.

Methods you might use include the node-voltage method, the mesh-current method, Ohm's Law, Kirchhoff's Voltage Law, and Kirchhoff's Current Law. Superposition would probably not be a good choice for this problem. Also, Watt's Law won't help you much.

Comment: What's Watt's Law, Elliot?

Comment: My thoughts exactly @glen_geek

Comment: @glen_geek as in what's 'appenin' 'ere ...

Comment: @glen_geek Something about pressure differential and steam flow rate, I would think :)

Comment: There is also the experimental method.

Comment: Watt's Law is P = VI for power consumed by a circuit element. I'll have to admit that I often see this formula without any reference to Watt, but one book I taught from had this name.